# Update Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this to display products on the Woocommerce empty cart page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'add_content_empty_cart' );

function add_content_empty_cart() {
echo '<h3>NEW</h3>';
echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="8" orderby="id" order="DESC"]' );
}
```

and this works, but since I have the add to cart button enabled for product listing, the cart page does not get updated when one of the products on the empty cart page are added to the cart - only when reloading the page, the contents of the cart are visible. How can I update the cart contents when a product from the empty cart page is added to the cart?

Answer (score 0):

To update the cart contents when a product is added to the cart from the empty cart page, you can use AJAX to refresh the cart dynamically without reloading the page.

First, you need to add a JavaScript file to your theme or child theme that will handle the AJAX request. The following code will add the necessary JavaScript code to your site:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Handle the AJAX request when a product is added to the cart
    $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function() {
        // Send an AJAX request to update the cart contents
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_cart_fragments_params.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // Replace the cart contents with the updated cart
                $('.widget_shopping_cart_content').replaceWith(data.fragments['.widget_shopping_cart_content']);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});
```

This code will listen for the added_to_cart event, which is triggered when a product is added to the cart, and then send an AJAX request to the server to refresh the cart fragments. Once the server responds with the updated fragments, the code will replace the cart contents with the new contents.

You should also make sure that the woocommerce_cart_is_empty hook is called after the cart has been updated. To do this, you can add a priority of 999 to the hook like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'add_content_empty_cart', 999 );
```

By setting the priority to 999, you ensure that the add_content_empty_cart function is called after the cart has been updated with the new product.

Comment: It does not change anything unfortunately.